# If statement results overwriting each other VBA

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, for-loop

I am experiencing a problem with the outputs from my loop. As the sub is running I can see that the results from the final IF statement are being overwritten by the results from the second one.  My code is structured as follows:

```
for i = 1 to 5
    for j = 1 to 50
        for each events.value in eventArray
            if events.value = arrayElem then
                if cells(i,j).value = "x" then
                    type = "col1"
                elseif cells(i,j).value = "y" then
                    date = "col2"
                elseif cells(i,j).value = "z" then
                    num = "col3"
                end if

                count = count + 1

                activeworkbook.worksheets("output").cells(count + 1, 1) = type
                activeworkbook.worksheets("output").cells(count + 1, 2) = date
                activeworkbook.worksheets("output").cells(count + 1, 3) = num

            end if
        next arrayElem
        if cells(i,j).value = "a" then
            name = "row1"
        elseif cells(i,j).value = "b" then
            size = "row2"
        elseif cells(i,j).value = "c" then
            height = "row3"
        end if

        activeworkbook.worksheets("output").cells(count + 2, 1) = name
        activeworkbook.worksheets("output").cells(count + 2, 2) = size
        activeworkbook.worksheets("output").cells(count + 2, 3) = height
    next j
next i
```

Obviously these are dumby variables and results, but the overall structure is the same as the real code.  I can see "name","size", and "height" being printed, but then they get replaced by "type", "date", and "num".   How do I prevent this from happening?  Each time a new event is found I need it to print its associated characteristics printed into a new row in the "output" sheet.

Comment: Put another `count = count + 1` before the latter three value assignments.

Comment: I was thinking `count = count + 1` should be moved to after all six assignments because the first 3 write from count+1 and the next 3 write from count+2

Comment: You have too much *cyclomatic complexity*, that's what's making your code hard to debug/maintain - extract the loop bodies into smaller procedures/functions that *do one simple thing*; then follow the execution path while explaining what's supposed to happen to a rubber duck. If you don't have a rubber duck, talk to your mug. [**No, I'm not kidding**](https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/).

Comment: @Jeeped  when I do that, it prints the results hundreds of times.  I believe that is due to it being looped through again for both the i and j loops.  I have tried placing it else where, but I have failed to find the correct location.

Comment: @jamheadart see my comment to Jeeped ^^

Comment: @Mat'sMug Doesn't everyone have a rubber duck to talk to?

Comment: @Dave - No, I talk to my rubber mug

Comment: How does this code even work - `for each events.value in eventArray` ... `Next arrayElem` ??!?!?  That is just wrong in so many ways.

Comment: @JonSnow have you tried for the latter 3 assignments as just `count+1` instead of `count+2`

Comment: @YowE3K in the real code it finds the event in a given range, eventCell, defined in the array, eventArray.  Once it is found I find certain characteristics to that event, which in this dummy case would be type, date, num, etc.

Comment: OK, it's a bit hard to tell what values you want in what rows, but I would recommend that you keep a counter of what row you are trying to write to, increment it just before you need to write something, and then write to cells in that row, e.g. `count = count + 1` `activeworkbook.worksheets("output").cells(count, 1) = type`. I.e. don't use `count + 1` when determining the row to write to (leave that up to the `count` variable to keep track of) and **consistently** update that `count` variable (i.e. don't decide to use `count + 2` to determine a row later on).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following simplified version of your code:

```
For i = 1 To 100
    If x = y Then
        rowNum = rowNum + 1
        Cells(rowNum + 1, 1) = "A"
    End If

    Cells(rowNum + 2, 1) = "B"
Next
```

Each time through the loop you are writing out either one or two things (two if `x = y` is true, one if it isn't) but you are only incrementing the row number by zero or one (one if `x = y` is true, zero if it isn't).  Even if you know that x will always equal y, you are still trying to write two rows of information out but only increasing the row counter by one.

Assuming you are not trying to replace the "B"s in my example with the "A"s from the next iteration through the loop, you should change the code to something like:

```
For i = 1 To 100
    If x = y Then
        rowNum = rowNum + 1
        Cells(rowNum, 1) = "A"
    End If

    rowNum = rowNum + 1
    Cells(rowNum, 1) = "B"
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I ended up separating everything into two loops.  One for type date num and one for name size height.